# Even with PHP plugin get_posts not working in widget area

Tags: php, widgets, get-posts

I have the following code in a template, it and displays images form a custom field:

```
<ul class="about-us-grid">
<li>
<?php $posts = get_posts('post_type=employee&orderby=rand&numberposts=16'); foreach($posts as $post) { ?>

<img  class="headshot" src="<?php the_field('headshot'); ?>">

    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

It works in a pagetemplate.php file but when I place it into a widget, it doesn't pull the php data. I'm using [PHP Code Widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/php-code-widget/). I've tried several other PHP widget plugins as well, so I don't thats the issue.
Do I have to code this differently for it work in a widget versus a template?

Answer (score 0):

Tuns out it needed: `global $post`

Complete working code:

```
<div class="aboutgridcont">
<ul class="about-us-grid">
<li>

<?php
global $post;
$posts = get_posts('post_type=employee&orderby=rand&numberposts=16'); foreach($posts as $post) { ?>

<img  class="headshot" src="<?php the_field('headshot'); ?>">

    <?php } ?>
</ul>

  </div>
```